# how to determine the weekend days in oracle table?

Tags: c#, oracle

i am developing a payroll system using c# and oracle. 
I have AttendenceTable that keeps record of all the employee's attendance (on daily basis) and then i want to calculate the salary based on total number of days an employee worked. the problem is how can i calculate number of days except the weekends and then calculate salary? Please help me to sort out this problem

Comment: Please edit in any relevant code you've tried.  We can better help you if we see where you are struggling, but we cannot provide code as a service.

Comment: i completed almost every thing, just stuck on this problem..

Answer (score 2):

With Oracle 11g, it is possible to determine if a date is a weekend this way, irrespectively of the NLS territory :

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE TO_CHAR (my_date, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
```

Comment: What if his NLS is set to a territory where the first day of the week is sunday?

Comment: it is easy to adjust the numbers in the `IN` clause in that case

Comment: There are plenty of ways to program this. Your answer works only if you're ABSOLUTELY SURE that weekends will always be days 6 and 7.

Comment: @ibiza, the NLS Territory can be different for each session, i.e. by default you don't know.

Comment: I modified my answer to be NLS independant

Comment: no, its not sure that weekends will be days 6 or 7. maybe an employee start working on the 3rd day of the week, then?

Comment: ok now problem is if employee joined on 15th of june, ie monday and he worked on regular bases till 19th ie friday of this week, and then its holiday. in next week he is absent for 2 days, how can i maintain this thing?? should i make a seperate  daily absent/present table in db to hold record of each and every employee? or what should i do?

Comment: If you need detailed information on each and every employee then yes you will require to have a table that tracks all you want. E.g. a table with columns `EmployeeId, DateWorked, TimeIn, TimeOut` or something along those lines and then have a program to interpret this data and calculate the metrics you need.

Comment: If you go the route of storing "time-in" and "time-out", plan that database carefully.  You can be certain that there will be multiple entries per person on occasion (went home for lunch, lunch meeting, doctor's appointments, family needs, etc).

Comment: yeah.. i had made a temporary table to store these occasions.. and at the end of the day final data will be stored to my main attendance table